# Is toResponse from ExceptionMapper thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, resteasy

I use `RestEasy` in my application and I have a very simple implementation of `toResponse` method from `ExceptionMapper` interface.

My question is: will this method have any problems in an environment where a massive amount of requests are happening(many requests will cause an exception to be thrown)? Will it have thread safety?

Comment: so you want to create one instance of exception and use(throw) it in multiple threads? Or each thread will create its own exception?

Comment: what i want to do is to bind it like this in the web.xml, i want this to be the exception handler for all exceptions that might be thrown anywhere in the code                                                                                  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>com.rest.exceptions.TestExceptionMapper</param-value>        
</context-param>

Comment: can you show me how?

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I still don't understand the question fully.

I used to use exception to response translation this way:
I define an exception class that `extends javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException`. Then in the constructor of my exception class I call a super constructor with appropriate params, e.g. `super(Response.status(404).entity(errorMessage).build())`

What is really nice about it is that you can even use a dto as entity and it gets translated.

Note that I don't use reasteasy. I use jersey with jackson.

So in my business logic I throw an exception, than it's handled by jaxrs and translated to response. There's no place for thread-unsafety ;)